# Verification of a limit with a doubtful result

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I tried to check this limit with the definition :

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\sqrt{x^2+1}=+\infty$$

I have studied that in order to verify this type of limit I have to solve the inequality:

```
f(x)> M
```

with Where M is a very large value decided by our choice.

So I had to solve:

$$\sqrt{x^2+1} >M$$

The result is this, but I'm not sure it's right. I should obtain, by solving the associated inequality, an unlimited interval above, but in the result I obtain both an unlimited interval above and an unlimited interval below.

Here is the result:

$$ x < - \sqrt{m^2-1} ,\quad x> + \sqrt{m^2-1}$$

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math.

Comment: Can you [show some work](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), because I don't know how you ended up with that result. In addition, there was no reason to use a picture for such a simple formula, try to use MathJax in the future. I did it for you this time

Comment: What Calvin Khor commented.  I also am very curious how you arrived at this result.  What counts is not whether your result is accurate, but that you worked on it.  However, mathSE reviewers can't examine your work until you **show it**.  Please do **not** respond with a comment.  Instead, please edit your query to show your work.

Comment: I changed the question for good. It should now be clear how I arrived at that result

Comment: Well you are not supposed to solve $\sqrt{x^2+1}>M$. If you think that way then you need revisit the definition of limit. It is not about solving inequalities but rather finding some constraints which ensure that certain inequalities hold.

Comment: Try to write the definition of limit (being infinity) for this specific function and then try to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

You are overlooking a few things:

1. Since you are taking the limit as $x \to +\infty$, you only need to be concerned about values of $x$ where $x > 0.$
2. There is a convention that for any non-negative $y, \sqrt{y}$ automatically refers to the non-negative square root.

Besides the above considerations, the result that you want is actually an indirect result of the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

The idea is that from the initial points in this answer, either the limit goes to $+\infty$, or there is an upper bound on $\sqrt{x^2+1}$, as $x \to +\infty$.  However, since $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ is strictly increasing as (non-negative) $x$ increases, the assumption that there is an upper bound on $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ implies that $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ must converge to some non-negative value $L$.  Assume the latter, and apply the squeeze theorem to obtain a contradiction.

That is, for all non-negative $x$, $x = \sqrt{x^2} < \sqrt{x^2 + 1}.$  Therefore, if there is a finite $L$ that represents the limit of $\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$, then you would immediately know, from the squeeze theorem, that as $x \to \infty, \sqrt{x^2}$ can not go to infinity.

Since $x = \sqrt{x^2}$, this is an immediate contradiction.

Comment: A much easier approach is via definition of limit and that matches the approach used in question. Using squeeze and contradiction seems too much here.

Comment: I agree that the OP's approach can be rehabilitated to be valid.  However, it is hard to imagine that it would be easier than the analysis in my answer, since my analysis involves very little math.  The hard part of my answer is that you have to be aware of the squeeze theorem and also be aware that an (upper) bounded strictly increasing sequence must be convergent.

Comment: The definition of limit in this case is easily handled by taking $M>0,N=M$ and then you see the obvious implication $x>N>0\implies \sqrt {x^2+1}>x>N=M$.

Comment: No need for squeeze or completeness of reals.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The *obvious implication* that you are referring to is actually a (somewhat) disguised form of the squeeze theorem.  Beyond that, I agree that the problem can be solved without focusing on the "completeness of reals", but why would you want to?  Isn't it better to expand intuition by noticing that an upper bounded strictly increasing sequence must be convergent?

Comment: I don't want to argue too much here. But the inequalities which I write are nothing but simple ideas available to any high schooler of age 12 or so. If that is sufficient why go further and introduce unnecessary complexity?